# Finding the cardinality of a union of cosets given their individual cardinalities

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a problem: To find $|H_1 \cup H_2 \cup H_3 \cup H_4|$ given $|H_1|=|H_2|=|H_3|=|H_4|=5$ And the cosets are distinct. And $H_i's$ are subgroups of a group G.

Do I just count out the identity element getting repeated three times, to get an answer of $|H_1 \cup H_2 \cup H_3 \cup H_4|$ - $|H_1 \cup H_2|$ - $|H_1 \cup H_3|$ - $|H_2 \cup H_3|$ $= 20 - 1 - 1 - 1 = 17$? Am I correct?

Thanks.

Comment: The identity need not be in a given coset. Maybe you can use that two cosets are either disjoint or equal, but then you'd need some information about the specific cosets $H_i$ of the question, say that no two were equal, or something.

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed in the question wrong!! Let me edit.

Comment: If the cosets are distinct they do not overlap at all so there are $20$ elements in the union of all four.

Comment: I'm new here, and I'm rushing. I have to edit again...

Comment: "subgroup" has a different meaning than "coset". If they are all subgroups and are distinct pairwise, then the count is $4 \cdot 5 -3$ since as you note the identity gets overcounted. But there is no subtraction of $H_i \cap H_j$ since that is the identity subgroup and so is not one of the four given $H_i$.

Comment: What do you mean identity subgroup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10819/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-arabhi-manachra)